# CKEditor not previewing image and showing error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor

Trying to configure the CKEditor in MVC 5 in asp.net. 
In View :

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })

 <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {  
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadImage","Administrator")',
   filebrowserUploadUrl: '@Url.Action("uploadnow", "Administrator")'
 });
</script>
```

Where  as my controller is

```
 public void uploadnow(HttpPostedFileWrapper upload)
    {
        if (upload != null)
        {
            string ImageName = upload.FileName;
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/uploads"), ImageName);
            upload.SaveAs(path);
        }

    }
```

This code is working fine. 
another action is :

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase upload, string CKEditorFuncNum, string CKEditor, string langCode)
        {
            string url; // url to return
            string message; // message to display (optional)
            message = "Image successfully saved ";

            //do save image code here
            url = "/" + Server.MapPath("~/Images/uploads") + "/" + upload.FileName;
            string output = @"<html><body><script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\", \"" + message + "\");</script></body></html>";

            return Content(output);}
```

I could able see the `"Browse Server"` button under `Image info` tab. Also able to add `Upload` tab. Where, on Upload window after selecting the image it is saving to the specified location but showing blank window without preview with text `"Send it to the Server"`. If I hit OK button it shows `Image source URL is missing.` Error message. What need to be corrected ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?